# EGit tag advanced does not expand

Tags: tags, egit

If I create a tag by highlighting a specific commit in the "History" view it works fine. But if I try to create a tag for a specific commit using the "Git Repositories" view as shown below, it fails. The "Advanced" drop-down arrow necessary to select the specific commit I want to tag does nothing. Is this feature not implemented yet? Is it in the works for EGit v3.1?

**Note:** I don't have a Eclipse project created yet. So I don't have a "Team" menu item. But I tried creating one and the result is the same - the advanced arrow doesn't work.

1. Create a new repo on Github (initialized with a readme.)
2. Clone the repo with EGit.
3. Make a commit on the master branch.
4. From the Git Repositories View in EGit:

   - Right-click the item "Tags"
   - Select the menu item "Create Tag..."
   - In the "Create New Tag" dialog box that opens up, enter a tag name, and tag message.

The "Advanced" drop-down arrow does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize the window after clicking on *Advanced*. After that, you should see a dropdown to select the commit to tag.

This was an issue in EGit, see [bug 352830](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352830). It's fixed in EGit 3.0.2 and 3.1 (not yet released).

Comment: Ahh, I should have noticed that since the arrow does change from pointing right to pointing downward. Thanks robinst.